# How to remap a MacBook keyboard to windows keys in bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bootcamp, mac

I just discovered bootcamp and I'm psyched that I can run Windows 7 RC on the MacBook Pro without using a virtual machine.  However the virtual machines run a bit better because they support remapping the MacBook's keyboard.  Currently I can't find an equivalent of the  <kbd>delete</kbd>  key (it is  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  +  <kbd>Delete</kbd>  when running Windows via Fusion or Parallels, but it doesn't work on a bootcamp install of Windows)

Has anyone come up with a clever workaround?

Comment: SU didn't exist when this question was posted. Now that it does I think this should be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Boot Camp Installation & Setup Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/boot_camp_install-setup.pdf).

Step 3 on Page 14 talks about installing the drivers from the DVD.  Also see page 17 for information about using the Mac keyboard in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Mac Keyboard drivers for Windows. I believe they are available on the MacOS DVD.

Answer (score 0):

install boot camp 3
try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>function</kbd>  key